# TEXTO Dentro de um botão - Materialize CSS

Tags: css, button, materialize

Estou com grandes dificuldades de quebrar texto dentro de um botão.
Faço uso do materialize css mas de forma geral nao faço ideia de como colocar todo o texto que eu queira dentro de um botão, ele sempre corta os final dos meus titulos e etc.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.6/css/materialize.min.css">


<c:when test="${p.parCodigoReg!=0}">
 <a href="impressaoBoleto.do?     codigoPar=${p.parCodigoReg}&parTipo=N&rel=boleto&portal=1" 
            target="blank" 
            class="waves-effect waves-light btn-large z-depth-4">
  <i class="large material-icons left">cloud</i>
    Imprimir Boleto de Mensalidade ParcelasRegulares   
  </a>
  <span>
    Próximo Vencimento: ${p.parVencimento}
  </span>
</c:when>
```

Answer (score 1):

Para que todo o texto caiba dentro do seu `button` você precisa alterar o `height` para `auto`, assim:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.6/css/materialize.min.css">

<style>

#botao {
    height: auto !important;
}

</style>


<c:when test="${p.parCodigoReg!=0}">
    <a href="impressaoBoleto.do?     codigoPar=${p.parCodigoReg}&parTipo=N&rel=boleto&portal=1" 
            target="blank" 
            class="waves-effect waves-light btn-large z-depth-4" id="botao">
  <i class="large material-icons left">cloud</i>
    Imprimir Boleto de Mensalidade ParcelasRegulares   
  </a>
  <span>
    Próximo Vencimento: ${p.parVencimento}
  </span>
</c:when>
```

Answer (score 0):

@Jonatas Almeida coloque o código para poder analisar.
Você precisa inserir as classes do Materialize para funcionar.
Ficaria mais ou menos assim:

```html
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.6/css/materialize.min.css">
        <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam accumsan semper ex id hendrerit.</a>
```